# Div overlapping the footer

Tags: html, css

I have found a timeline code on the internet but it seems to be behaving strange.
 Look at the image

[image: A line is overlapping footer]

I tried giving it position but it didn't work.

This is the timeline html and css
[CHECK](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/zigzag-timeline-layout)

Please help the poor. Thank you :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the footer div a z-index of 1. For example:

```
footer {
  z-index: 1;
}
```